# How to delete kubernetes failed/completed jobs

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

How can I clean up the failed and completed pods created by kubernetes job automatically without using cronjob. I want to keep only the last pod created by job.

How can we accomplish that?

Comment: You can set a [TTL](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#ttl-mechanism-for-finished-jobs) on your `Job` to have the pods cleaned up  automatically (which isn't exactly what you want, but may be your only option without writing some custom tooling).

Comment: already done by ain't working

Comment: If you've already done that then you should update your question to include your `Job` manifest so that we can see what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

`...clean up the failed and completed pods created by kubernetes job automatically without using cronjob`

If you specify [ttlSecondsAfterFinished](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#ttl-mechanism-for-finished-jobs) to the same period as the Job schedule, you should see only the last pod until the next Job starts. You can prolong the duration to keep more pods in the system this way and not wait until they are explicitly delete.

Comment: I have added this `ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 360` but still the failed/completed pods remain in the cluster

Comment: Your change will apply starting next Job. You will still need to delete the existing pod(s).

Comment: Even for new cronjob with `ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100` + `failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1` I can see a bunch of failed pods but there is not `Job`